# How to trigger Selenium test suite from Web Interface?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, selenium, automation

In our application, we have created Selenium test methods for many modules through C# Unit Test projects. We have configured all the selenium test methods with test categories(with sub-module info, smoke-test, regression-test, etc.,).

From web interface, we would like to set some configs for test methods(like credentials, environment variables) and should be able select and run run few test categories.

To achieve this,

1. I would like to have some web project created and have references to these Unit test projects.
2. Read all the categories from unit test projects and should be able to select few from the web interface.
3. Set some configs like enviroment variables, credentials from web interface and trigger the selenium testing.
4. Finally, i should get a test report with error details in case of failure.

I am not sure if this is really possible, please guide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what is it that you are asking? Perhaps you are looking for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_continuous_integration_software

Comment: I would like to know is it really possible with microsoft unit-test framework. If yes, how ?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking here. If you want a web front-end for your tests, just build a MVC app that does what you need. So instead of using tests, you could invoke your page objects from controller.. Just for the record, doing this does not make sense in my book.